# Display the level the user is at during a "drill down" in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

Let's say if I were to have a **clustered bar chart** on Power BI that have a *pseudo*-structure like this:

```
{" A": [
    {"A1": 1},
    {"A2": 2},
    {"A3": [
        {"A3-1": 1},
        {"A3-2": 2},
        {"A3-3": 3}
    ]}
]}
```

Where **A3** reflects the lowest number in the child elements (which is 1) and **A** reflects the lowest number in the child elements (which is also 1).

Upon loading the chart, the user has the ability to right-click to drill down from the first level to reveal the value for A1, A2 and A3. The same can be done for drilling down to A3.

I am wondering if a visual indicator can be created to show the user the depth s/he is at during the drilling down process? e.g. If the user is at the second level, an indicator to show the user is at the second level.

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking only about the built-in clustered bar chart visual, this isn't built-in functionality in Power BI.

However, the built-in bar chart visual does provide an indicator of where you are in a hierarchy. For example, in the below picture, I've drilled down 3 times (Year > Quarter > Month) and am now showing a breakdown by the 4th level (Date).

[image: Drilled Down Title]

The up-arrow in the top-left (indicated by a blue triangle) further indicates that I've drilled down and the greyed-out adjacent arrows indicate I'm at the lowest level. This isn't a numeric indicator and isn't as clear as a breadcrumb would be, but it is an indicator of the level you've drilled to.

In terms of a numeric indicator, it is possible a custom visual handles this better (now or in the future) or, though this is likely overkill, you could consider writing your own. Existing custom visuals can be found here: https://app.powerbi.com/visuals.

After reading this, you might be tempted to roll your own indicator via a separate DAX measure overlaid on top of the bar chart (using HASONEFILTER or HASONEVALUE for example).

I do not recommend this approach because an independent visual would rely on being cross-filtered by the bar chart when the user drills down. Right now, however, this does not happen, so the overlaid visual would have no way of knowing that a drill-down has happened. More information can be found here (and you can vote to fix this): https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/6709520-drill-down-should-drill-or-cross-filter-other-visu

Comment: Thank you, that's what I suspected too based on my extensive research on Google.

Comment: @Leonard why do you say it's not possible, when her request doesn't seem to mention cross filtering?

Comment: Since there is no numeric indicator on the built-in chart, the natural alternative approach would be to create a separate DAX measure that looks at how the chart is filtered and calculates where you are in the hierarchy (using HASONEVALUE or HASONEFILTER for example). This measure could then be rendered in a separate visual overlaying the bar chart. 1/2

Comment: However, this visual would need to be filtered at the same time that the user drills down into the chart, called cross-filtering in Power BI (otherwise the overlaid visual won't know that any drilling has happened). Since cross-filtering doesn't happen when a bar chart is drilled, taking this approach would not have the desired effect. 2/2